# Adding link_to method to image_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my index page I am displaying all registered users. When I click on their profile image it takes me to their page, however when I right click on the image to open in new tab it takes me to their photo url address only.

How can I add `link_to` so that when I right click on the image it opens the path to the user profile instead of the image url.

The related line should be:

```
  = image_tag user.avatar.try(:image_url)
```

_user.html.slim:

```
- if user.avatar.present?
  .common_box.box1 data-user-id="#{user.id}"
    .img_box
      = image_tag user.avatar.try(:image_url)
      -if @user.present?  
        ul.btn_link.hide
          li
            a.message_btn  href="#" data-user="#{user.id}"  data-mfp-src='#message_me'   Message
          li
            = link_to "Save", follow_popup_user_path(user), class: 'save_btn', :'data-mfp-src'=>'#follow_div', remote: true
          li
            a.report_btn href="#" data-mfp-src='#report_me'  Report
    .img_detail
      small years
      .circle
        span.age_box class="#{user.gender == 'Male' ? '': 'pink'}" = user.age
      h3 class="#{user.gender == 'Male' ? '' : 'pink'}" = user.username
      h4 
        = user.address
      div class= "#{user.gender == 'Male' ? 'green_corner': 'pink_corner'}"
        =image_tag "#{user.gender == 'Male' ? 'side_curv.png': 'curv_2.png'}"
```

Comment: i can see your image tag but where is your link to show profile page?

Comment: @Mandeep The line `.common_box.box1 data-user-id="#{user.id}"` takes you to the show page. However that is for only if you click on the box. If you right click on the box it will only popup the image url, not profile show page. That's why I was trying to figure out how to add a link_to method to the line `= image_tag user.avatar.try(:image_url)` so it can be use the show page instead.

Comment: I am curious, how are you defining both `user` and `@user`? You call `user.avatar.present?` as well as `@user.present`. I assumed this was a `_user.silm` partial, but then the @user would cause an error?

Comment: @xps15z you are calling your link by js and you want whole div to behave like a link?

Comment: @tehfailsafe I don't necessarily need `- if user.avatar.present?`, not sure why I added that originally to the pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a user defined as `user` already (guessing this is from a _user partial?) you should be able to something as simple as putting the image tag inside a link_to block.

```
- if user.avatar.present?
  .common_box.box1 data-user-id="#{user.id}"
    .img_box
      = link_to user do
        = image_tag user.avatar.try(:image_url)
      -if @user.present?
      // etc
```

Make sure the indentation is correct or slim will try to put everything indented past the link_to block in a link and the error that sometimes displays is tough to hunt down.

Comment: Thanks. This gets the job done. I have to make adjustments to my code since it throws off the CSS and spacing. But it does open the user show instead of the image url.

Comment: @xps15z do you know by doing this you are going to end up having several links inside link and they may not behave the way you want them to

Comment: @Mandeep Do you have an example of what you mean by the cons of adding `link_to` inside the box? I have tested 30 accounts thus far and each one are acting as expected (minus CSS changes required now). If you have a better solution let me know and I will implement and test it. `link_to` seems basic to what I need to get going.

Comment: @xps15z it's good that it seems to be working for you but a link inside a link is just bad html you can have cross browser issues with it and just think how it'll work you expect whole link to go to some url and then in between that area you want a particular portion to go to another page? I have had this issue and i think it wasn't working on ios so just thought i should warn you :)

Comment: The only thing inside the `link_to` block should be the `image_tag`, that's why I made a note about the indentation. I'm not sure how the `data-user-id="#{user.id}"` is working though, is that wrapping the whole thing in another link triggered with js? That would be ugly...  Though I guess this code already does have that before the `link_to` block addition.